# Foundation 1 row of 6 images on desktop and 2 rows of 3 images on mobile?

Tags: html, css, row, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I have 6 square images, all the same dimensions. I am trying to use Foundation to lay them out so that on desktop, they are on a single row but on mobile they are on 2 rows of 3, but I just can't figure it out. This is what I've tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image1.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image2.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image3.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image4.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image5.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 columns"><img src="{{ 'image6.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works alright on desktop(although there are some centering issues), but on mobile each image has it's own line.

This is what I am going for:

Desktop:
[image]

Mobile:
[image]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows (notice the "small" classes):

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image1.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image2.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image3.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image4.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image5.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns"><img src="{{ 'image6.jpg' | theme_image_url }}" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You rock! That was exactly what I was looking for :) Will accept this answer in 8 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define size classes for each div. You can use Foundation's [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids) instead. Simply define size classes in the parent element. This is Foundation way of achieving these type of layouts.

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-6">
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
</ul>
```